# webpack angular 9 with TFS build and deploy

Tags: angular, webpack, tfs

Our Angular web app has been using webpack to build and TFS to deploy without issue for over two years now.  Recently, the tokenization step in TFS is stalling because (I'm told) webpack is adding in __ (double underscores) to variable name and when the main.js file ends up with an odd number of __, it stalls.

Has anyone else seen this behavior or anything like it.

Suggestions

Comment: Only a step is stalling? In other words, the deploy is succeed. Did you get any error info in TFS release pipeline?

Comment: no the deployment is not succeeding....fail at the token-ionization, I'm being told its due to the number of underscores web pack is placing the in main.js file